# Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

What do I need to change here so that the JavaScript code works with the manifest version 2 and the security policy?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
function init()
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        url = tab.url;
        if(url.indexOf('chrome://') == -1 && url.indexOf('about:blank') == -1){
            document.main.q.value = url;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough source code. Look for inline event handlers (`onclick="init()"`, for example), and move the logic to an external script: `<script src="popup.js"></script>`, `document.getElementById('id-of-button').addEventListener('click', init);`. For more information about the CSP, see [Chrome extensions: Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working after I put the JavaScript code from the HTML file into an own file and added the following to the manifest file:

```
"content_scripts": [ {"js": [ "popup.html" ], "matches": [ "http://*/" ]} ],
"permissions": [ "tabs" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The inline event handler definition must be rewritten in terms of `addEventListener` and extracted into `popup.js`， so you should remove the `onfocus="this.select()"` in your `popup.html`, and in the `popup.js`, add the following lines:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('address_box').addEventListener('onfocus', this.select);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest versions of your library. I don't think you are using jQuery but if you do make sure you are using the latest version which supports CSP.
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11249

Both the extension and libraries code need to support CSP when you update to manifest version 2.